# Are $\cos^2 \theta$ and $\cos \theta^2$ the same?

Tags: trigonometry

Are $\cos^2 \theta$ and $\cos \theta^2$ the same?
I mean be it $\sin,\cos, \tan ,\cot ,\sec,\csc$. 
Are they same? Please help a maths noob here.

Comment: $\cos^2\theta$ is the same thing as $(\cos\theta)^2$, it's just another notation. But these are different from $\cos(\theta^2)$.

Comment: brackets are not mathematical jewellery only. They have a purpose....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

When you type $\cos^2 \theta$ you actually mean $(\cos \theta)^2$.

When you type $\cos \theta^2$ you mean  $\cos(\theta ^2)$.

Comment: Thanks now i confusion was cleared,my text book directly skipped many steps so i could barely understand,I'm just a high school entrant

Comment: @Trignometry Your textbook skipped many steps? I severly doubt that they skipped the step where the explained the notation $\cos^2(x)$.

Comment: Don't worry! It's normal to be confused at the beginning if the notation is not very clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

The first notation is used to mean
$$\cos^2 \theta = \left( \cos \theta \right)^2$$
Your second notation will usually be read as
$$\cos \theta^2 = \cos \left( \theta^2 \right)$$
although it is sometimes preferred to use the notation in the right-hand side to be clear.

They are not the same since
$$\left( \cos \theta \right)^2 = \cos\theta\cos\theta \ne \cos(\theta\theta) =  \cos(\theta^2)$$

Comment: Thanks  a ton for your help,I'm glad there's a community like this

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Why was there a downvote for question,did i ask something wrong ?I did search but could find anything help ful.
Let me know if i made some mistake so i could correct that in future

Comment: @Trignometry I didn't give the downvote, but I presume the downvote was due to your poor formatting. Using MathJax is encouraged.

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but I'll edit your question to the required formatting.

Comment: I'll learn mathjax before i post a new question in the future that's for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of syntax.

In handwriting or literature: $\sin^{2} x \equiv (\sin x)^{2}$ and $\cos x^{2} \equiv \cos (x^{2})$;

however for computer software, say ***Mathematica***:

**Cos[x]$^2$** refers to $(\cos x)^2$ while **Cos[x$^2$]** refers to $\cos (x^{2})$.

Should be very careful.